# Where to set the ""APPPATH" or "PATH_THIRD"" or "PATH_THIRD" variable?

Tags: ee2

There are lots of places used global variables like "APPPATH" or "PATH_THIRD"

> $path = ($native) ? APPPATH.$type.$pkg_name.'/' : PATH_THIRD.$pkg_name.'/';

I am having trouble with the $path value as it returned null. So I want to figure out where to set APPPATH variable?

---

> **Context:**
>
> In extensions.php, EE try to load modules. However, $path returns null

[image]

[image]

Thanks guys!

Comment: You should not have to set these constants - if they're empty then something else is wrong. In what context are you encountering this error?

Comment: @DerekHogue Thanks Derek! I have modified the question. This error is encountering when I try to migrate the current EE application to a new server. EE seems like cannot find the path to load extensions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a custom path to your third party add-on folder. My guess is that you have not updated `$config['third_party_path']` to reflect the path as it exists in your new server environment.

Comment: OMG! It's working now! What I did is I modified the variable **$env_config['third_party_path']** and **$base_url** in config/config.master.php. Thank you so much!! Derek! I have been struggling with this for 2 weeks. You saved my ass!

Comment: Can I ask one more question? The homepage and backend cms are showing perfectly. But when I click any link, it goes to the default server 404 page. Is it because of rewrite module, folder permission or something else? @DerekHogue

Comment: I fixed the 404 not found issue. The problem is the misconfiguration of  .htaccess file in /html folder. I will post my one in here for others. Anyway, thank you so much, Derek. It's a huge help!

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>